# How can i have a selectable row who start an activity and a checkbox who trigger a contextual menu at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my apps i have a customs Listview with an adapter.  In my list view i added a checkbox with *focusable=false* to make sure the listItem is still focusable.  On the *OnCheckedChangeListener* i call *list.setItemChecked* to make sure it trigger the contextual menu.  When a row is selected (not with the checkbox) it's starting an activity. (To Edit the row content)

In my activity i have these lines to start the contextual menu when an items is selected (with the checkbox)

```
transactionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
transactionList.setMultiChoiceModeListener(multiChoiceMode);
```

**The problems is**  because of CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL when the contextual menu is shown i'm not able to click on row again. When i click on row it only select or unselect rows.

I was thinking to use CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE instead of CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL and start the action by myself, but i don't know if there is a better way to do what i want to do.

In fact, what i want is exactly like the Gmail apps.  You can select rows to have custom action (delete, share, whatever), but you still can click on a row to see the email. (even if the contextual menu is poped out)

Thanks in advance !

Ps. English is not my first language, but i'm pretty sure you can understand what i'm saying. (So sorry in advance for english mistake)

**Edit** added some code, but i just want to understand what would be the best to do.  I know this code use like half the old method where you couldn't click a row when the contextual menu is open and half of the refactor i did to manually trigger the actionbar
http://pastebin.com/Tig0qYcN

by the way, my code is on github

Adapter: https://github.com/Dalto/PersonalBankManager/blob/master/PersonalBankManager/src/org/madduck/personalbankmanager/model/adapter/TransactionAdapter.java

Activity : https://github[DOT]com/Dalto/PersonalBankManager/blob/master/PersonalBankManager/src/org/madduck/personalbankmanager/AccountFragment.java

Note my github code could change and could became not related to the question

Comment: show some code with what you have done, the adapter specifically

Comment: @tyczj I added some code, but i don't think it will really help you, i'm using basic stuff and i only want to know a way to do it. My code is working but with the bug of cannot click on a row while the context menu is open.  And if i change to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, the MultiChoiceModeListener callback will not be trigger by himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by myself.  I don't know if it's the way to do, but it's working.

I'm using

```
transactionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

instead of

```
transactionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

and added this code when a checkbox is checked

```
    if (transactionAdapter.countSelected() > 0) {
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(multiChoiceMode);
        }

        NumberFormat amountFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        actionMode.setTitle(amountFormat.format(transactionAdapter.getTotalAmountSelected()));
    } else if (transactionAdapter.countSelected() == 0 && actionMode != null) {
        actionMode.finish();
    }
```

If you prefer here the commit i did on github : https://github.com/Dalto/PersonalBankManager/commit/b6f46f7261ae2eef1f7b6fb2d2258a0da1779211

If someone ever find a better way to do it (i mean a cleaner way with Android API) just post it after, it may help someone else.